# How to organize local folders in Chrome DevTools workspace?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am using Google Chrome DevTools, and I have to support several projects. I am often editing my source files directly in DevTools, so I added my local source folders to the DevTools workspace. What is bothering me: there seems to be only one workspace, and DevTools only shows the names of the folders I added - which are just 'src' or 'scss' most of the times. So with every new project it becomes increasingly difficult to pick the right folder when I want to open a file.

Is there any way to organize the local folders in DevTools so that I can see to which project they belong? Something like multiple workspaces, virtual folders or symbolic names for the added folders would help, but I couldn't find anything like that in DevTools or in the Chrome extension repos.

Answer (score 2):

You can have as many workspaces as you like. You just need to add each project directory.

1. Navigate to the root of your project directory in Chrome. This will be your workspace.
2. In the Sources panel of DevTools, right click the path and click 'Add folder to workspace'.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for the second project directory

### Example

The example is with local system files but it will work much the same with a local web server, such as one set up using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`.

[image: Creating workspace]

As you can see, I now have two separate directories so there's no confusion between the apps.

[image: Multiple workspaces]

You can add your network mappings either in the Sources tab, or in the Workspaces panel in DevTools settings. I recommend the latter, as it is clearer.

[image: Workspace mappings]

Comment: It's the "Workspace" panel in the settings, and the context menu says "add folder to workspace" - both singular. So I disagree with "as many workspaces as you want". Your proposal boils down to adding a whole project folder instead of only the subfolders that I want to map. I am bit frowning upon DevTools having access to many more files this way - but nevertheless, it is a simple and efficient solution to my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Matthias You can use the `Excluded folders` option in the Workspace panel, which may help with your situation. I agree that the naming seems off. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?hl=en#add-local-source-files-to-workspace) refers to them as "workspaces", so they are plural, but the context menu seems to be missing this. I will log an issue and see if we can get that changed.