# Why is typescript source code missing in dist?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, source-maps, angular-cli-v6

Angular CLI compiler generates source-maps (`.map` files) which allow debugging the original typescript code in Chrome developer tools. I'm already using this feature when developing locally with the JIT compiler / `ng serve`.

However, when I build a preview-version for my web-server with the AOT comiler / `ng build`, I cannot debug the code, although all map files can be found in the `dist` directory. The reason is that `ng buid` didn't export the source code `.ts` files to the `dist` folder.

What's the purpose of the source-maps if the source code is missing?

How can I achieve that the relevant source code (`.ts`) is exported to `dist` on `ng build`? Is there a cli parameter or setting for `angular.json`?

**EDIT**

I understand the purpose of the source-maps without source files now (see comments) - The intention is to debug the source code on your local file system. Chrome allows to add mappings to local files for that. However I'm still looking for a way to provide the original source code with my app for several reasons:

- I have very bad experience with Chrome's "add folder to workspace" feature. Sometimes files are not reckognized, breakpoints are ignored, Chrome crashes.
- One might suggest to use the IDE's debugger to work around these issues. However, I still haven't found a way to configure *WebStorm* for debugging typescript files when attaching (!) a Chrome debugger. Debugging typescript works with *WebStorm* with Node.js or JavaScript-Debug configurations, but not with the "Attach Node.js/Chrome" debug configuration. I debug the app running on a mobile device, so I have to use this debug option.
- Other developers should be able to debug the application even if they work on a different branch / code base.

When I wrote this question I thought something is configured wrongly. Now that I understand the intention of Angular's source-maps, I ask you if there is a workaround to provide the source files. For instance `angular.json` allows to specify asset rules, but I wasn't successful when trying to leverage them for this purpose.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231406/how-to-organize-local-folders-in-chrome-devtools-workspace If you want to use chrome for debugging, you should add your source folder. You don't want to place your source-code in your dist folder. I strongly recommend using an IDE for writing and debugging your application (vs-code, webstorm, ...)

Comment: Your code is being minified and uglified, why would you want to debug it in pseudo-production mode ? Just copy the settings in your `serve` command and it gives the same output, and you can debug there !

Comment: It's not a pseudo-production mode. We are building a cordova app and I have to debug the device. But from the perspective of common web applications it totally makes sense to exclude the source files, thanks.

Comment: @PieterWillaert I tried this and it doesn't work very well. Some source files cannot be debugged for unknown reasons. I cannot remember even once that the "add source to workspace" feature of chrome worked correctly. Of course I use an IDE, but I prefer Chrome dev tools for JS/TS debugging.
@trichetriche Which settings? `serve` provides a web server which also serves the source code files

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an new environment, add settings for this environment and build using this configuration. See example:

Create new environment file environment.dev.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://192.168.1.11',
  port: ':2992',
  api: 'api',
  debug: true,
  type: 'dev'
};
```

Add the environment build settings in angular.json under the configurations section. Notice the 'sourceMap' boolean:

```
"dev": {
  "fileReplacements": [{
     "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
   }],
   "optimization": true,
   "outputHashing": "all",
   "sourceMap": true,
   "extractCss": true,
   "namedChunks": false,
   "aot": true,
   "extractLicenses": true,
   "vendorChunk": false,
   "buildOptimizer": true
}
```

then build with this environment

```
ionic cordova build android -c dev
```

Comment: The `sourceMap` boolean is already set to `true` in my configuration. The source-maps would not be genereted if it was `false`. Your configuration is very similar to mine and it does not copy source files to `dist`. However, we don't use Ionic. Maybe Ionic has this feature.

Comment: The points of the source map files are that they reference to your original source code, so you can debug your minified bundled code containing your source files with source maps.